# is async really making sense here? NpgSQL with F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, npgsql

I have the following transaction:

```
let insertPositionsAsync accountId timestamp (positions: PositionInfo list) : Async<Result<int, ExchangeError>> =
    async {
        try
            use connection = getConnection location
            do! connection.OpenAsync()

            use writer =
                connection.BeginBinaryImport(
                        $"COPY {accountId}.{tablePositionsName} (ts,instrument,average_price,leverage,unrealized_pnl,side,initial_margin,maintenance_margin,position_initial_margin,open_order_initial_margin,quantity,max_notional)
                        FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"
                    )

            for t in positions do
                do! writer.StartRowAsync()                                                     |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(timestamp,                       NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.Instrument.Ticker,             NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)   |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.AveragePrice,                  NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.Leverage,                      NpgsqlDbType.Integer)   |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.UnrealizedPnl,                 NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.Side.ToString().ToLower(),     NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)   |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.InitialMargin,                 NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.MaintenanceMargin,             NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.PositionInitialMargin,         NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.OpenOrderInitialMargin,        NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.Quantity,                      NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(t.MaxNotional,                   NpgsqlDbType.Double)    |> Async.AwaitTask

            let! c = writer.CompleteAsync()
            return Ok (int c)

        with ex ->
            error $"insertPositionsAsync {ex.Humanize()}"
            return Error (ServiceException ex)
    }
```

my understanding is that the loop:

```
            for t in positions do
                do! writer.StartRowAsync()                                                     |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! writer.WriteAsync(timestamp, NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) |> Async.AwaitTask
                ...

            let! c = writer.CompleteAsync()
```

is happening in the driver and it's just collecting data in some local storage. Does it make sense to have all these async blocks then? (performance wise).

But the async API must exist for some reason. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a discussion of this API [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1632). It starts with someone saying:

> It would be helpful to have asynchronous versions of BeginBinaryImport and BeginBinaryExport so they can be used from e.g. api endpoints without blocking the server.
>
> For Import, given the write happens on Close/Dispose I'm guessing the write methods would not become async

However, one one of the developers then comments that:

> Write can also block. So you need WriteAsync too.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that in many (even most) cases, the APIs on NpgsqlBinaryImporter will complete synchronously, since they simply write to Npgsql's memory buffer. This is true not just for individual value writing (WriteAsync), but for StartRowAsync as well - none of these APIs perform I/O unless the internal buffer is full.

So in effect, you're streaming out an arbitrarily long stream of data to PostgreSQL, via a memory buffer. Given enough data (after all, this is a "bulk import"), at some point the buffer will be exhausted and the API will flush; the question is whether that flush should block the calling thread or happen asynchronously.

So yes, it does make sense to use the async APIs, if you want I/O to happen asynchronously (even if most calls don't result in I/O). There should be very little overhead for calling the async methods (as opposed to the sync ones), so the async ones should generally be the default; but measure the overhead yourself to get the full picture.

Answer (score 2):

As with any performance related question, the only meaningful answer is  *measure it and see for yourself!*

More generally, async makes it possible to do the communication with the database without blocking an operating system thread. This may or may not have performance implications - but it depends on what else is happening in your program.

- If you just have a single logical process communicating with the database, it makes no difference whether you do this in a synchronous or asynchronous bit of code.
- If you want to write data to a database, you could do this from multiple concurrent writers. In this case, async would make a difference as you could create more concurrent writters. But I think it would likely not help much - because the database will probably not be able to write faster when you have excessive number of writer threads.
- A more interesting case is when you are doing something else in your program. For example, if you have a web server than needs to handle many concurrent requests, it makes sense to use asynchronous communication with a database - because it will not block threads that you need to handle other web requests.

The summary is, you should measure the performance - but it will likely depend on what else is going on in your program. I do not think changing a single threaded writer script to async would make any difference (aside form adding some small overhead).

Comment: in this scenario, I have around 6-7 threads writing a few thousand rows every few seconds so there is a lot of concurrency. But since the COPY operation is filling a buffer, I question having an async block for writing each value as writing a double will not result in a network operation, but it'll just end up as a write in a memory buffer. Eventually one of them will will the buffer and will become blocking, but the vast majority will only represent overhead.

Comment: so I was questioning if it would make sense, as long as I stay within the buffer limits, to do a sync write and then an async flush

Comment: If you have six threads writing data and your application is not doing other things (e.g. being a web server processing incoming requests), then I think you could just happily run six threads with synchronous code.

Comment: That's often my dilemma: doing async vs. putting code in its own permanent thread and not caring about blocking. I've never benchmarked the pros and cons.